# How to manage network adapters?

Tags: gui, network-interface, internet

Let's pretend i have two wireless adapters, one is usb and one is pci and they are named wlan0 and wlan1.

Is there an easy (and graphical, if possible) way to force applications to use one adapter or the other ?

For instance, i want to run iceweasel using wlan1, and qBitTorrent on wlan0. How can it be achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

The application normally has to support it. You'll find some applications can bind to an IP address or hostname instead (if it has that setting), and then it'll magically go through the interface where the IP is configured.

Example, I use irssi. In my configuration, I have a line like this.

```
hostname = "temple.example.net"
```

When it starts, it finds the IP associated with that name (DNS lookup, also looks at /etc/hosts), and then binds appropriately to that IP. It successfully goes through the interface set with that IP.